# MySql inner select bad performance

Tags: mysql, performance, select

I have 2 tables in MySql DB:
t_big (very large table), with PK of (item_id,time).

t_item (small table ~ 20K rows), with PK of item_id. This table also have an index on the column group_id.

When I run an explain on the query (which is supposed to return 5 rows):

```
explain select * from t_big where item_id in (select item_id from t_item where group_id = 5885)      and TIME >= 1417380000 and TIME < 1417380600;
```

I get a bad result (~ 2 million rows scanned on t_big).

Using inner join didn't help.

But, when I replace the inner select with its results, it solves the problem (the explain shows only a few rows scanned on t_big). When I did this, the query looked like this:

```
explain select * from t_big where item_id in (9001,9002,9003) and TIME >= 1417380000 and TIME < 1417380600;
```

There must be a way for me to run this query without a full scan more elegantly (instead of running the inner select before I run my query and inject its results).

Does anyone know a better/different way?

Comment: It would probably see the EXPLAIN plans for all three variants ...

Comment: probably you need index on group_id field in t_item? Can you paste the output of explain?

Comment: Do you have an index over `(t_item, TIME)`? If not, make one (i.e., and index that contains two fields, not two indexes).